# Man-in-the-middle: Intercepting an applications function/library calls

Tags: performance, time, environment, jail

Basically, what I want to achieve is to run a program in an environment which will give any value asked by the program on basis criteria decided by me. Say e.g., games regularly query system about the time so as to execute animations, now if I have a control over the values of time that are passed on to the program I could control the speed of the animation (and perhaps clear some difficult rounds easily :P).

On similar grounds keystrokes, mouse movements could also be controlled (I have tried Java's Robot class, but did not find it satisfactory: slows the system {or perhaps my implementation was bad}, the commands are executed on currently focused programs and can't be targeted specifically).

Any graceful way of doing it or some pointers on achieving it will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You would basically write your own operating system. The program (your game) does basic system calls (to the operating system for the date, time, input devices, to graphic libraries (directx, opengl) to draw stuff,)..

Comment: Looking for things on "Automation" might help.

Comment: @Konerak What I have in mind is to intercept the function calls made by the programs and then return a value of my choice. Any comments?